# Shrub with white flowers and lemon-jasmine scent

Tags: identification, shrubs

We bought our house & neglected garden 1.5 years ago. Last spring a somewhat scraggy shrub surprised us with a few white flowers on two or three branches that had a very strong lemony, jasmine scent.

After some judicious, yet heavy-handed pruning and a generous dose of feeding, we were rewarded with a full bloom this spring.

Some details: The flowers appear before the leaves start to emerge (bloom is almost over now and the leaves are pushing trough). This year bloom started in mid-March, last spring at the end of February, but we had an exceptionally mild (or none at all) winter of 2013/2014.

- The flowers are slightly waxy and a bit translucent, around 2cm (3/4 in) in size. The scent is strong, like a mixture of jasmine and lemon.
- It's deciduous, but a few leaves remain on lower, protected branches, see last picture.
- The bark on older branches turns grey and tends to peel a bit, younger branches are golden brown, see first picture.
- The average height is 1.5m (5ft) with a few individual branches up to 2m (6.5ft).
- It's growth is rather "loose", even in summer with full foliage one can somewhat "see through" it.

But as it remains yet unidentified and hence unnamed, I trust in your expertise...

[image: close-up with bark]

[image: Second close-up]

[image: last year's leaves]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Lonicera fragrantissima, one of the shrub type honeysuckles. Flowers best against a protecting wall or fence. Best time to prune is immediately after flowering has finished - remove a third of the flowered shoots and reshape the rest as required. Benefits from an organic mulch (well rotted garden compost/manure) applied after pruning. Ultimate height and spread around 2 metres x 3 metres.

Comment: Well, it looked scraggy, so I'm not surprised you gave it some serious attention - but yes, at exactly the right time!

Comment: In addition, these shrubs are leaners, so planting next to a fence is a great idea.